# $\mu$-finitely supported functions

Tags: measure-theory, functions, complex-numbers, lebesgue-measure, dense-subspaces

Here's the question;

[image]

I need the lead to start the question. I tried the Lusin theorem for the density of the functions but it didn't work. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Step functions are dense in all $L_p$ ($0<p<\infty$) If you built integration frommmeasures, this is obvious by dominated convergence. If you built the integral from functional analysis (Daniell-Stone) this is by construction.

Comment: yes agreed that simple functions are all dense in $L^p$ which also have step functions in its formula but we don't have any step function in the statement.

Comment: step functions, or rather simple functions have support of finite measure.

Comment: Thanks. that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X$ is $\sigma$-finite, there exists a sequence of sets $E_n \subseteq E_{n+1}$ such that $\mu(E_n) < \infty$ and $X = \bigcup_{n \geq 1} E_n$.

By the dominated convergence theorem, if $f \in L^1(X)$ then $\int |f - f 1_{E_n}| d\mu \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ which implies the result.

Comment: Thanks. I just have a question, We have $|f_{E^c}|=0$. How does that lead us to have a step function?

Comment: @mathlearner I am not claiming that any function appearing in this answer is a step function?

Comment: I meant $∫|− 1_{}|$ because we have been given $f|_{X\E}$. Can you please explain this part?

Comment: You want to find a sequence of functions $g_n \in L^1(X)$ such that $g_n$ is $\mu$-finitely supported and $\int |f - g_n| d\mu \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. My claim is that you can take $g_n = f1_{E_n}$. None of the functions involved are required to be step functions.

Comment: Got it!! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't think $\sigma$-finitness is needed.

Recall that for any measurable function, there is a sequence of simple functions $s_n$ such that $|s_n|\nearrow|f|$ pointwise $n\rightarrow\infty$. For example, for $f\geq0$
$$s_n=\sum^{n2^n-1}_{k=0}\frac{k}{2^n}\mathbb{1}(2^{-n}k\leq f< 2^{-n}(k+1)) + n\mathbb{1}(f\geq n)$$
is such a sequence. 
It is easy to check that for any $r>0$,  $|f-s_n|^r\leq 2^r|f|^r$. Thus by dominated convergence, if $f\in L_r(\mu)$,  $\|s_n-f\|^r_r\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$.

Notice that integrable simple functions have support of finite measure (why?).

Comment: Thank you! Makes sense. I have certain additions to the proof. Will be posting it soon.